# how to properly (or alternatively?) shutdown linux from terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown

I wrote `sudo shutdown now` on my ubuntu VM terminal and the results were not what i expected. I expected results similar to shutting down through the desktop GUI but instead it shut down rather quickly and brought me to a recovery prompt (i think it was apache's, maybe not) and started up again.

How do i shutdown the way i am expecting through the terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

halt will do what you're looking to do.

```
sudo halt
```

Otherwise I believe you wanted to do

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

[Source](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ushutdow.htm)

Comment: -1 for citing `halt`; `halt` is semantically meant to kill all processes immediately; `shutdown` ensures a clean shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```